# Is the time spent on query or on moveToNext in SQLite?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, user-interface

In an Android app, you use the method [`ContentResolver.query()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#query%28android.net.Uri,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String%29) to query a URI. As a result, you get a `Cursor` object, and then you just execute [`Cursor.moveToNext()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#moveToNext%28%29) repeatedly to read your data from the database.

Is it OK to do the `query()` in a background thread (e.g. `doInBackground` of an `AsyncTask`) but the `moveToNext` calls in the GUI thread (e.g. `onPostExecute`)?

That is, is the time spent mostly on the `query()` so the `moveToNext` calls are fast or, on the contrary, the behavior is lazy and the actual query execution is postponed until the data is requested?

Comment: Seems like some `System.nanoTime()` calls would clear this up pretty easily...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Android, SQLite cursors do not read the data until the first call that needs to know whether the query returned some records or not, but then read all data into a cache.

So the first `moveToNext()` call is the one that is slow.
You might want to add a `getCount()` call in your background thread.